# php & lighttpd code behind mechanism?

Tags: php, lighttpd

I inherited a website code base that I am trying to get familiar with.  First of it is powered by lighttpd and php.  My struggle with it is that the php executables aren't named as such, meaning instead of having a samplewebpage.php, the former developer opted to name the file as samplewebpage.html with nothing inside (i.e. empty file) and has a code behind file called samplewebpage.data which then contains all the php codes.  Could someone please tell me how is this set up like this?  I am trying to rebuild the environment on a new server in order to document a build book just in case future developers might need to rebuild a similar server.  So anyone kind enough to comment on how it would be possible to set up a php/lighttpd environment in this way where the php codes doesn't go in the main html file but in a separate file with the same name but different extension?  (samplewebpage.html --> samplewebpage.data).  Thanks for any help or pointers.

Comment: Could you please put some code/text format inside your question? It's unreadable..

Answer (score 0):

From the scant information I've given, I would imagine this is performed by rewrite rules.

A good place to start is the /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf config file and take a look for `url.rewrite`